# Retain cycle with ARC, NSOperationQueue and dispatch_source_t (timer)

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nsoperationqueue, retain-cycle

I have a method that adds an operation to the serial NSOperationQueue. Since I want to call the method on a regular basis, I use dispatch source timer.

However, this method can also be called in response to user actions. When this happens (e.g. a moment before the method is called due to timer) I extend timer's fire date.

The problem is the code I've written has a retain cycle and I don't understand where.

Here is the reduced example that demonstrate the problem (don't forget to set deployment SDK to 10.7):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface MyObject : NSObject

@end


@implementation MyObject
{
    NSOperationQueue *_queue;
    dispatch_source_t _timer;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [_queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
    [_queue cancelAllOperations];
    dispatch_source_cancel(_timer);
    dispatch_release(_timer);
}

- (void)scheduleTimer
{
    if (_timer)
    {
        dispatch_source_cancel(_timer);
        dispatch_release(_timer);
    }

    _timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0));

    if (_timer)
    {
        __weak MyObject *selfBlock = self;
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(_timer, ^{
            dispatch_source_cancel(_timer);
            [selfBlock doMethod];
        });
        dispatch_source_set_timer(_timer, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER, 0);
        dispatch_resume(_timer);
    }
}

- (void)doMethod
{
    NSLog(@"doMethod");

    __weak MyObject *selfBlock = self;

    [_queue cancelAllOperations];
    [_queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [selfBlock scheduleTimer];
    }];
}

@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
        [obj doMethod];

        sleep(10);

        obj = nil;
        NSLog(@"something still points to obj");

        sleep(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged with ARC, but how can you call dispatch_release there?

Comment: @Eiko Dispatch objects do not require dispatch_release if min deployment SDK is 10.8 So you still have to manually release them under 10.7

Comment: Where are you discovering the retain cycles?  I ran your code in Instruments with deployment target of 10.7.  It detected no cycles.  The static analyzer did not show any retain cycles.

Comment: @NSBum The MyObject instance is never deallocated (unless app is terminated of course). I expect it to be deallocated soon after `obj = nil`. Unfortunately something keeps the references to the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't actually a retain cycle here.  The issue is that something you are doing or the innards of `dispatch_release()` (I didn't take the time to figure it out) is sending an `autorelease` message instead of a `release` message and so the final `release` doesn't happen until after your `autorelease` block closes.  If you change your `main` routine to the following it'll show you things working as you expect:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        MyObject *obj = nil;

        @autoreleasepool {
            obj = [MyObject new];
            [obj doMethod];

            sleep(10);

            NSLog(@"set to nil");
            obj = nil;
        }

        sleep(1);  // need this to give the background thread a chance to log

        NSLog(@"something still points to obj?");

        sleep(10);

        NSLog(@"done sleeping");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I changed your other code to add some logging and clean up a few things, but commented out the changes that are just for nit picky clean coding :) and it still works fine.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface MyObject : NSObject

@end


@implementation MyObject
{
    NSOperationQueue *_queue;
    dispatch_source_t _timer;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [_queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
    [_queue cancelAllOperations];

    if ( _timer )
    {
        dispatch_source_cancel(_timer);
        dispatch_release(_timer);
        // _timer = nil;
    }
}

- (void)scheduleTimer
{
    NSLog(@"Schedule timer");

    if (_timer)
    {
        dispatch_source_cancel(_timer);
        dispatch_release(_timer);
        //        _timer = nil;
    }

    _timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER,
                                0,
                                0,
                                 dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0));

    if (_timer)
    {
        __weak MyObject *selfBlock = self;
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(_timer, ^{
            dispatch_source_cancel(_timer);
            [selfBlock doMethod];
        });
        dispatch_source_set_timer(_timer, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER, 0);
        dispatch_resume(_timer);
    }
}

- (void)doMethod
{
    NSLog(@"doMethod");

    __weak MyObject *selfBlock = self;

    [_queue cancelAllOperations];
    [_queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [selfBlock scheduleTimer];
    }];
}

@end
```

Here's the output I get:

```
2013-03-10 18:15:33.829 testtimer[35328:403] doMethod
2013-03-10 18:15:33.832 testtimer[35328:1e03] Schedule timer
2013-03-10 18:15:34.833 testtimer[35328:1e03] doMethod
2013-03-10 18:15:34.835 testtimer[35328:2203] Schedule timer
2013-03-10 18:15:35.837 testtimer[35328:1e03] doMethod
2013-03-10 18:15:35.839 testtimer[35328:1d03] Schedule timer
2013-03-10 18:15:36.839 testtimer[35328:1d03] doMethod
2013-03-10 18:15:36.841 testtimer[35328:1e03] Schedule timer
2013-03-10 18:15:37.842 testtimer[35328:1e03] doMethod
2013-03-10 18:15:37.844 testtimer[35328:1e03] Schedule timer
2013-03-10 18:15:38.846 testtimer[35328:1e03] doMethod
2013-03-10 18:15:38.848 testtimer[35328:1e03] Schedule timer
2013-03-10 18:15:39.849 testtimer[35328:1e03] doMethod
2013-03-10 18:15:39.851 testtimer[35328:1d03] Schedule timer
2013-03-10 18:15:40.851 testtimer[35328:1d03] doMethod
2013-03-10 18:15:40.853 testtimer[35328:2203] Schedule timer
2013-03-10 18:15:41.854 testtimer[35328:2203] doMethod
2013-03-10 18:15:41.856 testtimer[35328:1e03] Schedule timer
2013-03-10 18:15:42.857 testtimer[35328:1d03] doMethod
2013-03-10 18:15:42.859 testtimer[35328:1d03] Schedule timer
2013-03-10 18:15:43.831 testtimer[35328:403] set to nil
2013-03-10 18:15:43.861 testtimer[35328:1d03] doMethod
2013-03-10 18:15:43.861 testtimer[35328:1d03] dealloc
2013-03-10 18:15:44.833 testtimer[35328:403] something still points to obj?
```

If you take out the `sleep(1);` call you'll see that the "something still points to obj?" log happens before the last `doMethod` & `dealloc` log statements. I suspected this was just threading and NSLog buffering which is why I put in the `sleep(1);` and sure enough the behavior changed as I expected it would.

Also from the docs for `dispatch_queue_create` in Xcode documentation viewer it says this:

> Any pending blocks submitted to a queue hold a reference to that queue, so the queue is not deallocated until all pending blocks have completed.

which makes sense and also might impact the timing of the various deallocation actions.